# Traversing through an array of objects

Tags: loops, object, flutter, dart

```
{
"Catalog": {
    "shirts": [
        {
            "id": "93453951-8427394-234723908",
            "name": "Demin Shirt",
            "price": 100.0,
            "category": "Random Category",
            "available": true,
        },
        {
            "id": "93453951-8427394-40325978",
            "name": "Random Shirt",
            "price": 500.0,
            "category": "Random Category",
            "available": true,
        }
    ],
    "Jeans": [
        {
            "id": "4802345-348579-5983452-23423",
            "name": "Bare Denim Jeans",
            "price": 2000.0,
            "category": "Some Category",
            "available": true,
        },
        {
            "id": "143682137-3481293-239842",
            "name": "Levis jeans",
            "price": 1000.0,
            "category": "Some Category",
            "available": true,
       }
    ]
}
```

}

How do I traverse this array of objects such that I am able to display all the different types of shirt under the category shirt and all the jeans under the heading jeans.

Something like this:

- Shirts

  - Denim Shirt.
  - Random Shirt
- Jeans

  - Bare Denim Jeans
  - Levis jeans

Answer (score 1):

**Generic Solution**

This is an object, not a list, so you can't just plug it into a loop. If you want to loop through all the values and sub-values, you will have to do it recursively.

```dart
void recurseObject(dynamic value) {
  if (value is List) {
    // value is a list, iterate over its children
    for (var child in value) {
      recurseObject(object);
    }
  } else if (value is Map) {
    // value is an object, iterate over its keys and recurse the corresponding values
    for (var key in object.keys) {
      print(key);
      recurseObject(object[key]);
    }
  } else {
    // value is a primitive, so just print it
    print(value);
  }
}
```

---

**Specific to your Object**

If your object has a set structure, then you can just grab all the bits you want and set up some nested loops.

```dart
final catalog = rootObj['Catalog'] as Map<String, Dynamic>;

for (var category in catalog.keys) {
  final categoryList = catalog[category] as List<dynamic>;
  print(category);
  for (var value in categoryList) {
    final name = value['name'];
    print(name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is pure JSON. You need to first convert it into a Dart object.

There are a few ways to do the conversion. I've found the easiest way is to use an online converter such as this website: https://app.quicktype.io/

After you convert your JSON to an object, you could traverse it like this:

```
printCatalog() {
 var catalog =
    Catalog.fromRawJson("Here's where you need to pass in your JSON");

 print("Shirts: ");

 catalog.shirts.forEach((shirt) {
   print(shirt.name);
 });

 print("Jeans: ");

 catalog.jeans.forEach((jean) {
   print(jean.name);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use dart:convert library, and json.decode. Then access whatever you want in your json.
I fixed your JSON as it wasn't set up right, here is the complete solution.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var jsonstring = '''{
    "Catalog": {
        "shirts": [{
                "id": "93453951-8427394-234723908",
                "name": "Demin Shirt",
                "price": 100.0,
                "category": "Random Category",
                "available": "true"
            },
            {
                "id": "93453951-8427394-40325978",
                "name": "Random Shirt",
                "price": 500.0,
                "category": "Random Category",
                "available": true
            }
        ],
        "Jeans": [{
                "id": "4802345-348579-5983452-23423",
                "name": "Bare Denim Jeans",
                "price": 2000.0,
                "category": "Some Category",
                "available": true
            },
            {
                "id": "143682137-3481293-239842",
                "name": "Levis jeans",
                "price": 1000.0,
                "category": "Some Category",
                "available": true
            }
        ]
    }
}''';

  Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(jsonstring);

  print("--COOL SHIRTS--");
  for (var shirt in data["Catalog"]["shirts"]) {
    print(shirt["name"]);
  }
  print("\n--COOL JEANS--");
  for (var jeans in data["Catalog"]["Jeans"]) {
    print(jeans["name"]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
--COOL SHIRTS--
Demin Shirt
Random Shirt

--COOL JEANS--
Bare Denim Jeans
Levis jeans
```